# How to pass parameter from controller to view, view to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, breadcrumbs

Assume I had a method action called 'ReceivedMessages' that shows all the received messages.
In that page, if you click on any message, it redirects to its 'Show' page.

I can go that 'Show' page from 'SentMessages' also.

It has to be judged where that 'Show' page comes from either 'ReceivedMessages' or 'SentMessages'

It's for breadcrumbs purpose. It has to be something like this

Home > Received Messages > A Message        or
Home > Sent Messages > A Message

To make this links, I have to pass the path to Received Messages view, and from there to 'Show' controller to create 2nd link in my Breadcrumbs.

How can I archive this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the params you want in the url path of your links, like this:

```
<%= link_to "Show Message", message_path(:id => @message.id, :breadcrumb => 'ReceivedMessage') %>
<%= link_to "Show Message", message_path(:id => @message.id, :breadcrumb => 'SentMessages') %>
```

Then, in your controller you make your logic with these params.

```
params[:breadcrumb]
```